Grafana: Unable to zoom in Trend graph
I’m asking help about the possibility to do zoom in Trend Graph, in the same way as Time Series Graph.
I see that if I click on the graph and move the mouse I’m able to select a window, but when I release the mouse button it disappear without zooming in.
I want to ask if there is something to enable during the creation of the grafana container or if someone had the same problem and found a solution to it. Or, if a solution does not exist! :D
I tried to search for any possible flag or configuration in the right-side panel during the creation of the Trend Graph dashboard but no info is found (as well in Time Series, where it works by default).
Thanks a lot!


Trend visualizations should be used for datasets that have a sequential, numeric X that is not time.

Trend assumes that you are not using a timescale (or at least not linked to the time range you select in the dashboard), otherwise you would use a time series panel. Example: horsepower per rpm.
Zoom-in like you described is to change the time range ("I am seeing a month, I want to see a specific week" -> instead of manually choosing it in the time picker, select range on graph). The trend panel doesn't implement this behaviour as it's not using the time range.
I do see a case of setting a min-max X in Trend with it. I do encourage you to evaluate if doable and propose a Pull Request on the source code.

You're right. I do a "wrong" example. I understand about time series. I'm thinking about a zoom like XY chart, that permits to select a window to zoom in, and a double click to revert.
